# Is $T$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be the space of all polynomials in one variable over $\Bbb R$. If $p=a_0+a_1x +a_2 x^2+...+a_n x^n$,define $||p||=|a_0|+|a_1|+...+|a_n|$.

Which are correct?

1. $(X,d)$ is complete where $d(x,y)=||x-y||$.
2. $T:X\to X$ where $T(p)=a_0+a_1 x +\frac{a_2}{2} x^2+...+\frac{a_n}{n} x^n$ is continuous.

   3.$T $ is bijective and a homeomorphism.

Obviously it is not complete as $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+..\notin X$.

It is continuous since $||x_n-x||\to 0\implies ||Tx_n-Tx||\to 0$

It is bijective since it is injective and surjective since $T(a_0+a_1x +2a_2 x^2+..+na_n x^n)=a_0+...+a_n x^n$ .

Also $T^{-1}$ is continuous  and so $T$ is a homeomorphism.**But the correct answer given is only 2**.

What is the fault?

Please help.

Comment: Why do you think that $T^{-1}$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p_n(x) = \frac 1n\cdot x^n\in \mathbb R[x]$, then $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence such that $p_n\rightarrow 0$ for $n\to\infty$. But $T^{-1}p_n(x) = x^n$ and $x^n\not\rightarrow 0$ for $n\to\infty$. Hence $T^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that $T^{-1}$ is not continuous. In fact
$$\frac 1n x^n \to 0 \ \ \ \mbox{ as $n \to \infty$}$$
but $$T^{-1} \left( \frac 1n x^n\right) = x^n$$
does not approach to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\|x^n\| = 1$ but $\|T^{-1}(x^n)\| = \|nx^n\| = n$, so $T^{-1}$ is not bounded and thus not continuous.

To see that $T$ is continuous you can also notice that $\|Tp\| \leq \|p\|$ for all $p$, so if $\|p\| = 1$ then $\|Tp\| \leq 1$, showing that $T$ is bounded.